# NodeJS location header without cache

Tags: node.js

I have problem with my simple NodeJS app. I am using `connect` with `express-session` module.

```
module.exports.logout = function (request, response, next) {
if (request.session.user) {
    request.session.destroy(function (error) {
        next(error);
    });
}
response.writeHead(301, 'Please login', { 'Location': 'login' });
response.end();
};
```

The problem is logout page. Whan I run app and firstly logout user i works fine, but when I login second time and logout it only redirect to login page without logout user. I think the problem is because browser use cache for redirects. How to force it?

Comment: You need to wait for `destroy()` to finish.

Comment: But when I create header in callback function I get error "headers already send". Could you show short code how to properly code it?

Comment: You need to only send a response once, not twice.

Comment: If the page should not be cached make sure it has these minimum set of HTTP headers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks!